# How to control Word layout used when opening file?

Tags: microsoft-word, layout

How can you configure a Word file to always open in a given layout when you mail it to other people?

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason documents look different on one machine as compared to another is the printer.

When Word displays a document in "Print Layout" form, it actually uses the characteristics of the currently selected printer to determine what the layout should look like. Obvious items such as default margins, paper size, and other charaterstics of printers in general can have a document appear quite differently when viewed, or printed, on one system versus another.

To display the document identically on other computers you should convert them to PDF.

More details from the [**source.**](http://ask-leo.com/why_does_my_microsoft_word_document_display_differently_on_different_computers.html)